# Upgrade Cypress to latest version not working without force install

Tags: node.js, cypress

I have just upgraded Cypress using `npm install cypress -D` and got the below error

```
up to date, audited 775 packages in 1s

18 packages are looking for funding   
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Repositories\XXX-testautomation> npx cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 7.2.0

  ×  Verifying Cypress can run C:\Users\<UN>\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.2.0\Cypress
    → Cypress Version: 7.2.0
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.


Platform: win32 (10.0.19042)
Cypress Version: 7.2.0
```

But when I perform force install, I am able to see the confirmation that the install was successful and I was able to open cypress without any issues.

```
npx cypress install --force

Cypress 7.2.0 is installed in C:\Users\<UN>\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.2.0

Installing Cypress (version: 7.2.0)

  √  Downloaded Cypress
  √  Unzipped Cypress
  √  Finished Installation C:\Users\<UN>\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.2.0

You can now open Cypress by running: node_modules\.bin\cypress open

https://on.cypress.io/installing-cypress

PS C:\Repositories\xxx-testautomation> npx cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 7.2.0

  √  Verified Cypress! C:\Users\<UN>\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.2.0\Cypress

Opening Cypress...
```

Can someone explain why it always needs a `--force` command?

Comment: Had the same problem with this version (failed verify step), just ran cypress open a 2nd time and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I run at the same problem and I use the [this guideline](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Clear-Cypress-cache) and run commands in this sequence that usually helps:

```
cypress cache clear
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

During an upgrade, it may be missed to clean up cache files. If any issue with the upgrade try to do cache clear (using `$cypress cache clear` command) or find the cache path using `$cypress cache path` command clear it manually then install cypress `$ npm install cypress --save-dev`

npx executes binaries from npm packages and it won't install. Refer the [diff](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/prabhumohan09_npm-npx-nodejs-activity-6656575459414900736-2cu-)

Comment: See the 2nd message above, `npx cypress install` ... `Installing Cypress (version: 7.2.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

**npx** used only for launch the packages, not for install.
Also I faced issue with install the version 7.1.0 - enabled vpn crash my installation. After disabling vpn - installed the cypress successfully. Maybe the problems with connection?
Try to use the 7.1.0 version.